# Arithmetic Progression proof by induction

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, induction

Let $a,d, x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and this be the given arithmetic sequence:

$$a_{1} := a, \forall_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}: a_{n+1} := a_{n} + d$$

Now I am want to proof with induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ a_{n} = a + (n-1)d$$

To do this, I tried the following:

Base case: $n=1$, $a_{1} = a = a+(1-1)d = a+0 = a$

Induction step: Suppose that $ a_{n} = a+(n-1)d$. Then

$$ a_{n+1} = a_{n} + d = (a + (n-1) d) + d$$
 $$= a + dn - d + d
= a + dn $$

Where did I go wrong here? When I try to set $n = 0$, instead of $a$ I get $a+d$ now.

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: You didin't go wrong and you get  what are you supposed to get.

Comment: you are not suppose to get $a+d$.

Comment: You already get what you need. See that $a_{n+1}=a+nd=a+[(n+1)-1]d$

Comment: If you set $n=0$ you get $a_1 = a+d \cdot 0 = a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its perfect just finish it by $a+nd = a+((n+1)-1)d$ so your formula is true for $n+1$ .qed by induction/